# Where is "Create Test Module" in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Before I switched to Android Studio I was using "Create Test Module" in IntelliJ IDEA to create test module to keep my unit tests in there. I can't find it in Android Studio though. How can I create it to write and run tests? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can put them in the same module as the sources of your apk. 
Create a directory structure like this:

```
-<Project root>
  |-<Module name>
    |-src
      |-main
        |-com
          |-<company name>
            |-<app name>
      |-instrumentTest
        |-com
          |-<company name>
            |-<app name>     <- Put your unittests here
```

You can run them by create a new run configuration in Android Studio. Select a new Android Test run.

Comment: Do you have to change your classes package name from `com.<company name>.<app name>` to `main.com.<company name>.<app name>` ?

Comment: No, that's not needed.